# How to access table in laravel using eloquent with is not directly attached

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following table structure and i want to access Portal which is assigned to specific case but using patient info. For example i have the following query

```
$data['patients'] = Patient::with('operator')->where('case_id', $case_id)->get();
```

this query returns the operator assigned to the patient now hare i want the portal name assigned to the patient using case.

Portal Table

```
id   Name   
1   A
2   B
```

Cases

```
id     Name    case_number     patient_name     user_id     portal_id
1      Farz       456            sania             5           1
```

Patient

```
id    case_id   operator_id
2     456            5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you properly created the laravel relationships among `Portal`, `Case`, `Patient` and `Operator` models, you can access in this way:

```
// you get Case model
$case = \App\Case::findOrFail($case_id);

// patients: there is a hasMany relationship between Case and Patient models
$data['patients'] = $case->patients;

// there is a belongsTo relationship between Case and Portal models
$portal_name = $case->portal->Name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use another relationship

```php
$data['patients'] = Patient::with('operator', 'cases.portal')
                             ->get();
```

In Patient :

```php
public function cases(){
    return $this->hasMany(Case::class);
}
```

In Case :

```php
public function portal(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Portal::class);
}
```

then you can access it with :

```php
foreach($data['patients'] as $patient){
    foreach($patient->cases as case){
         $var = $case->name;
    }
}
```

or if you just want all portal names :

`$portals_names = $data['patient'][0]->pluck('cases.portal.name')`

Answer (score 0):

Normaly, if you did the correct relations in your models, you can only use :

```
$data['patients'] = Patient::with('operator')->where('case_id', $case_id)->get();
$portals = [];

foreach ($data['patients'] as $patient) {
    foreach ($patient->cases as $case) {
        $portals []= $case->portal;
    }
}
```

I suppose there is a `HasMany` between Patient and Cases, and a `BelongTo` between Cases and Portal ?

If you want to lazy load the data, you can try :

```
$data['patients'] = Patient::with(['operator', 'cases.portal'])->where('case_id', $case_id)->get();
```